# Makefile: pick the right file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a source code with thousands of media files and the following file structure:

```
files/module/file.vid
files/module/lang/file.vid
```

if '`files/module/lang/file.vid`' exists, I want to copy it to target as is.

if not, I want to copy '`files/module/file.vid`' into '`files/module/lang/file.vid`' in target.

How can I do that with makefile?

PS: to be more precise, can the solution fit in the current piece below?

```
$(foreach lang,$(filter-out en-US,$(gb_HELP_LANGS)),$(eval $(call gb_AllLangPackage_add_files_for_lang,helpcontent2_html_media_lang,$(lang),$(LIBO_SHARE_HELP_FOLDER)$(if $(HELP_ONLINE),/$(PRODUCTVERSION))/media, \

files/scalc/$(lang)/imtrigon.vid \

files/scalc/$(lang)/trigon.vid \

files/scalc/$(lang)/pivot.vid \

files/scalc/$(lang)/functions_ifs.vid \
 )))
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "copy it to target" or "copy ... in target".  Is "target" some other directory you've not described here?

Comment: yes, target is the destination directory of the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
VIDDIR := files/module
LANGDIR := $(VIDDIR)/lang
TARGETDIR := target

VIDFILES := $(notdir $(wildcard $(VIDDIR)/*.vid))

TARGETVIDS := $(addprefix $(TARGETDIR)/,$(VIDFILES))
LANGVIDS := $(addprefix $(LANGDIR)/,$(VIDFILES))

all: $(TARGETVIDS) $(LANGVIDS)

$(TARGETDIR)/%.vid : $(LANGDIR)/%.vid
        cp $< $@

$(LANGDIR)/%.vid: $(VIDDIR)/%.vid
        cp $< $@
```